# How to read data from CSV and use it to convert it to Bratt(.ann) format python

Tags: python, csv, nlp, annotations

So I have a [csv file](https://github.com/Da-vid21/Outputs/blob/main/test_singlefile.csv) and I wanted to convert it to Bratt (ann) format so it would [look like this](https://github.com/Da-vid21/Outputs/blob/main/test.ann) is there a script I can use to do this? Thanks

Comment: I think this question is either too broad or incomplete. As far as I can tell Brat annotations files contain the result of adding annotations to a text, either manually or through some AI(?) see more info here https://brat.nlplab.org/introduction.html

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I'm sorry about that I thought I linked the final ann file but I didn't, if you take a look at the ann file maybe that would help https://github.com/Da-vid21/Outputs/blob/main/test.ann

Comment: I was thinking if I can loop through the rows use the start and end data to only select that section of the sentence and then convert it to ann file but I'm new to python and the pandas dataframe isn't easy to loop rows